# Ubuntu 14 Graphics

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics

In my current Ubuntu computer  I have a Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV370/M22 [Mobility Radeon X300] and I'm wondering how to get better divers for it I tried to install fglrx but could not get it working.  I also would like to update my opengl here's the result of `lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV370/M22 [Mobility Radeon X300] [1002:5460] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:2006]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    I/O ports at de00 [size=256]
    Memory at dfdf0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at dfd00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5751 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1677] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Latitude D610 [1028:0182]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
```

P.S. I'm a Linux user who understands the command line however I'm not that great with Linux drivers and that is why I'm asking here